# Magento 1.9 Frontend cookie issue

Tags: php, magento, cookies

Please help with below in Magento:

Issue: stale cookie leading to failure of AddtoCart.
Cookie domain was domain.com with expiry of 1 month. It was changed to www.domain.com with same expiry.

The cookies are not getting refreshed. We have cleared all the caches on server side but the cookies are not getting cleared on browser side.

We have tried updating/renew the cookies but it is not helping.

Browser is sending both the cookies in request.

Can anyone please suggest what is to be done to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

please check your cookie domain setting in

System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management

It needs to exactly match your domain (including www). Also check if you have all correctly set for the storeview.

Comment: @Nik please accept the answer then, so it doesn't show in unanswered section. thank you in advance